# Reshaping a batch for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

By using an LSTM AutoEncoder I am facing some problems in the shaping of the dataset accordingly for the LSTM needs.
Since I am training on batches, I generate a loop of windows of my time series - the code looks like this:

```
X_batch = np.array(file.loc[window * WINDOWS_SIZE:(window + 1) * WINDOWS_SIZE - 1], dtype="f")
print(X_batch.shape)
X_batch = np.reshape(1, WINDOWS_SIZE, cluster_feature_size)
print(X_batch.shape)
history = model.fit(X_batch, X_batch, epochs=1, verbose=False)
```

My batches are shaped of 48 data points(WINDOWS_SIZE) and 45 metrics (cluster_feature_size variable).

I have read that I need to reshape my data in the following format `(samples, timesteps, features)` but I am failing somewhere and lacking of some information.

My assumption is that 1 sample is 1 batch and in a batch I have 48 data points and therefore I set 48 timesteps.

A draft of the model architecture I built so far is the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(WINDOWS_SIZE, cluster_feature_size)))
model.add(RepeatVector(WINDOWS_SIZE))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

I followed an online tutorial and I am still working on it.

The error I get is this one, while I am reshaping:

```
(48, 45)
---> 17 X_batch = np.reshape(1, WINDOWS_SIZE, cluster_feature_size)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (48,)
```

Comment: What is the shape of `X_batch = np.array(file.loc[window * WINDOWS_SIZE:(window + 1) * WINDOWS_SIZE - 1], dtype="f")` when you run `print(X_batch.shape)`?

Comment: could you try with this: `(X_batch.shape[0],WINDOWS_SIZE,X_batch.shape[1])`?
the 1 is odd so could you also give us the first print please

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I added the print of the shape as you asked and modified the reshape code but still getting the same error:
`---> 17 X_batch = np.reshape(X_batch.shape[0],WINDOWS_SIZE,X_batch.shape[1])`
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (48,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of a reshape here:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(48, 45)
X = np.array([X])
print(X.shape)
```

gives me:

```
>>> (1, 48, 45)
```

As i don't know more the context i can't help you more, but that should solve the reshape issue.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I have an archicture error probably. Is the architecture bad fitting the purposes of an AutoEncoder? I just found on a tutorial those layers but I am not sure of their effectiveness. I just want to create a reconstruction through an AutoEncoder that exploit LSTM cells.
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_4 to have shape (48, 1) but got array with shape (48, 45)` while running the fit method

EDIT: I solved this error by modifying` model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))` in `model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(feature_cluster_size)))`

Comment: well the dense 1 at the end sur kills everything. it return a single value for all input You then have no chance of finding a sample. the two other layers make sense but really i can't say what the point of doing this. Be sure to read carefully the tutorial to see if you've not missed a part. this can be the Encoder but should be train with a decoder i don't see here.